# Python TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found

Tags: python, operating-system, tuples, typeerror

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os

print "Scan a file for ""ErrorScatter"" payload"
print "Drag the suspicious file here then press enter."
filepath = raw_input("File Location: ")
fixpath = filepath , "/Contents/MacOS/ErrorScatter"
scan = os.path.exists(fixpath)
```

So i am making a program to check if a file has a "ErrorScatter" payload but i keep coming across and error when testing my creation. Since i'm a newb i do not know how to fix this.

This is the error i'm getting:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
```

Would anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `fixpath = filepath + "/Contents/MacOS/ErrorScatter"`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

, operator in Python is used to create tuples, for example

```
1, 2, 3
```

makes 3-element tuple

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

and

```
"blah", "bleh"
```

means 2-element tuple

```
("blah", "bleh")
```

To concatenate strings, you could use `+` as [Gaurav already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28826241/python-typeerror-coercing-to-unicode-need-string-or-buffer-tuple-found#comment45923460_28826241):

```
fixpath = filepath + "/Contents/MacOS/ErrorScatter"
```

but in fact the better way is to

```
import os

fixpath = os.path.join(filepath, "Contents/MacOS/ErrorScatter")
```

or even

```
fixpath = os.path.join(filepath, "Contents", "MacOS", "ErrorScatter")
```

(using `os.path.join` is a habit you will appreciate once you happen to run some scripts on windows, this one is not too likely but habits grow by repetition...)